# Create a regex with target text having varying key-value pairs?

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing some regex to do some config file validation automation which I intend to include in to a CICD pipeline, but I'm facing some issues getting the regex to work properly on certain strings.

I have strings like the following:

```
Filter:Class=ABC_Root_Base;
Filter:Class=Logfile_Base;
Filter:Class=Logfile_Sendmail;
Filter:Class=Daemon_Notice;
Filter:Class=Logfile_Syslogd;msg=re:'syslogd: restart';
Filter:Class=Logfile_Cron;msg=re:'CMD';
Filter:Class=Logfile_Cron;msg=re:'STARTUP';
Filter:Class=AppLog;sub_source=MTResourceMonitor;msg=re:'support';
```

Rules are:

1. Filter lines must start with "Filter:"
2. Filter lines must end with a semi-colon
3. Each key-value pair within a filter line, must terminate with a semi-colon (and multiple key-value pairs are allowed within a single filter line)

I need to validate them using some regex, but I'm having some challenge getting it to match strings properly when they have multiple key-value pairs in them. It works fine with just a single key-value pair though.

For example, the following string would match fine:

```
Filter:Class=Logfile_Base;
```

However, the following doesn't correctly match:

```
Filter:ClassAppLog;sub_sourceMTRMonmsg=re:'su;dnsdjs;
```

The start and end of that string above is fine, but there are no semi-colon separators between key-value pairs and so it's actually invalid. It breaks rule number 3.

Here is the regex I created thus far, which works sometimes as above:

```
^Filter:.*=.*;$
```

Comment: What is your regex platform?

Comment: @anubhava It's Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^Filter:(?:\w+=[^;]*;)*$
```

[online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/q8AcU3/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^Filter:       ##Matching Filter: from starting of value.
(?:            ##Starting a non-capturing group from here.
  \w+=[^;]*;   ##Matching \w(1 or more occurrences) followed by = till a semi colon comes, including ; in match.
)*$            ##Matching 0 or more occurrences of regex mentioned above till end of value.
```

***NOTE:*** Change above regex to `^Filter:(?:\w+=[^;]*;)+$` in case you want to match at least 1 match of value-key pair, only change here is from `*` to `+` in regex.